# Hooks are placed on a wrong origin

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, bones

I'm rigging the wing of the bird `Piero training course by CG Cookie` but I'm stuck on `Episode 23`,called : `23_piero_rigging_wing-part1`.

I should create 4 new hooks,one for each joints of the wing. In the picture below,You can see that the 4 joints as origin have the point situated inside the black circle. This is the goal that I need to reach as stated by the tutorial. My problem is that though I do the same steps as the author,those 4 joints are placed in a different origin : inside the left eye. Why there ? I created a small video to show you and I added the blender file. Very thanks.

[image: goal to reach]

[video : what I do](http://sendvid.com/idf4ympe)

[image]

Comment: Can you put the video on youtube? When I clicked on the link it did indeed send me to send vid, but when I clicked on the play video button it sent me to a website with a virus in it. Luckily I just tasked kill my web browser before anything bad could happen...

Comment: Also shouldn't CRTL+ALT+C then O work?

Comment: It is never happened to me that playing the video it sent to a website with a virus. Should I press CTRL + ALT + C then O,when,how ? In edit mode,object or ? I uploaded the video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQVHy-_81QQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, I watched the video but couldn't see the moment where he showed the origin of the hooks.

However, I think you should look into the "Set Origin"-options. You can open them by pressing "Space" and typing "Set Origin" into the appearing text box. Or just use the short cut "Shift + Alt + Ctrl + C".

Select all the hooks and choose one of the options. Try out whether one of them results in the wished origin position.

Greets
Jaspa

--- EDIT ------------------

Ohh god, I fixed it xD
You always tried to give the empty elements the origin. But first: empty elements have no origin, just a location (see my link in the comments for more details). And second: That's not what was  done in the tutorial.

To achieve the same origin as in the tutorial, you need to select the armatures (the whole bird) in Object Mode. Therefore you just need to click any bone. Once selected, you need to center the 3D cursor (as described in the comments too). Now you can use "set origin" options for applying the new origin. Et voilà: You've got the same settings as in your tutorial.

Have fun :)

Comment: hello. I tried to do what you said,but it didn't work. check this video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3GxueGVjFg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Ok, tried it our myself, really didn't work.
But if you're just looking for the effect: can't you select the hooks and then position the cursor in the center via "Space" > "Snap Cursor to Center". If you change the pivot point to 3D cursor (the second dropdown menu on the left of viewport settings [solid, rendered, wired...]), all changes will be made related to the 3D cursor.

Comment: It does not work again,check here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kezNzZDwAp4&feature=youtu.be ; maybe I didn't undestand very well what you suggest. Can you make a short video to show me what to do ? thannks.

Comment: What is your specific aim? I do not know, how to set the origin in this case.But if the actual aim is scaling them to the center, for example, my second advice is enough. Why do you need the origin to be in the center?

Maybe this post also answers your question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32931/set-pivot-point-of-empty-object

Comment: I'm not sure about the reason why I should do this,but I see that in the tutorial that I'm following,the piero training course by cgcookie,this is a goal that I need to reach. If I don't reach it,in the next tutorials of the series,I could have problems.... this picture shows that the author did it : http://i.stack.imgur.com/59Ov5.png

Comment: it worked. you are great.